# Assigning one character array to another gives Error. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, assignment-operator

Name of an array is pointer to the first element. So Why one character array cannot be assigned another array ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char str1[]="Hello";
  char str2[10];
  char *s="Good Morning";
  char *q;
  str2=str1;  /* Error */
  q=s; /* Works */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array, but you can *copy* to it.

Comment: "Name of an array is pointer to the first element" - no, an array _decays_ to a pointer to its first element. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in expressions automatically converted to pointer pointing to the first element of the array except for operands of `sizeof` operator and unary `&` operator, so you cannot assign to arrays.

Adding `#include <string.h>` to the head of your code and using `strcpy()` is one of good ways to copy strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
  char str1[]="Hello";
  char str2[10];
  char *s="Good Morning";
  char *q;
  strcpy(str2, str1);  /* Works */
  q=s; /* Works */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: char str[] is same as char *str. Do you mean that an array once declared cannot point to any other memory ?

Comment: @SaketAnand No. `char str[]` is NOT same as `char *str` unless it is in arguments of function.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Name of an array is **not the same** as a pointer to the first element. In some cases, the array name decays to the pointer to the first element but in general, they are not the same.

Coming to your problem there, array names are not modifiable lvalues, so they cannot be assigned.

Quoting chapter §6.3.2.1 for `C11`, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*

> [...] **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type,** does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified
>   type.

For assignment operator, the LHS should be a modifiable lvalue.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16,

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

In your case,

```
 str2=str1;
```

`str2` is not a modifiable lvalue. Hence, you get the error.

FWIW, to copy the contents, you can use `strcpy()` from `string.h` header file.

Comment: But be careful using strcpy! Note that bad things will happen if you execute `strcpy(str2,s);`